# Syslog error: kernel: [653405.280073] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17

Tags: linux-kernel, syslog

I'm new to linux, i need your advise and help on this error that i'm seeing from syslog. 
My log file is showing me all about this error. Any issues with this? It seems to be abnormal.

```
Dec 12 10:17:46 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [652924.320084] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:18:18 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [652956.384081] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:18:50 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [652988.448082] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:19:22 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653020.512085] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:19:55 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653052.576086] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:19:55 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653053.391096] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=06:58:1a:3a:fe:b7:06:69:60:76:7b:3e:08:00 SRC=210.193.31.242 DST=172.31.26.163 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=119 ID=8222 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43076 DPT=443 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
Dec 12 10:19:55 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653053.391379] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=06:58:1a:3a:fe:b7:06:69:60:76:7b:3e:08:00 SRC=210.193.31.242 DST=172.31.26.163 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=8223 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30787 DPT=443 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
Dec 12 10:20:01 ip-172-31-26-163 CRON[27534]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Dec 12 10:20:05 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653063.000627] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=06:58:1a:3a:fe:b7:06:69:60:76:7b:3e:08:00 SRC=210.193.31.242 DST=172.31.26.163 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=8224 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30787 DPT=443 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
Dec 12 10:20:05 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653063.000960] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=06:58:1a:3a:fe:b7:06:69:60:76:7b:3e:08:00 SRC=210.193.31.242 DST=172.31.26.163 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=119 ID=8225 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43076 DPT=443 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
Dec 12 10:20:27 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653084.640081] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:20:59 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653116.704078] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:21:31 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653148.768079] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:22:03 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653180.832083] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:22:35 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653212.896081] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:23:07 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653244.960089] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
Dec 12 10:23:39 ip-172-31-26-163 kernel: [653277.024076] xen:balloon: reserve_additional_memory: add_memory() failed: -17
```

Comment: You should always provide more information on the version of the kernel you are on along with the flavour ? Looks like this is a know issue which may require upgrading the kernel. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1304001

Comment: I'm sorry did not provide the details. Version : 3.13.0-29-generic. May i know this issue will cause any issues to the server ?